# Ethminer continue mining and getting new jobs but not making "Submitted and accepted."

Tags: mining

I used 4x1060 6GB, and ethminer on Linux 16 and overlock GPUs
When i start script everythings works ok, but after some hours, everything look ok, I receive new jobs but my miner to making "Submitted and accepted."

I already switch internet from wifi to cable, and same situation.

I think it can be 3 possible problems

- Overlocking (possible)
- Internet Provider (uploading issues)(i test internet speed and it was fast)
- Linux GPU drivers (possible)
- Pool(I had others machines, and they are working ok with same pool)

Maybe `smbd` can advice how to find that problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say for sure, try resetting the clocks back to factory defaults.  I have been mining with EthOSDistro for over a year and half with no issues.  My rigs run for days and sometimes weeks without a reboot.

I also mine to dwarfpool, you could try pointing at a different mining pool to see if that is the issue, rule that out and narrow down the area to look at.

Lastly check your config file to ensure your url's and ports are correct and scan for malware to ensure your computer has not been compromised.

Comment: Question can be closed, the problem was, that i used wrong parameters of etherminer, I used OpenCL, but when swith to CUDA, everything became normal . Because i have Nvidia GPU